Cant locate the class
I started a website, a YouTube clone, I am trying to go to channel/channel_name/edit but when I try to do that it says Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Channel] does not exist.
I've tried remaking it on a different Laravel version, but to my surprise that didn't fix the issue. I've checked the route and the class itself. I think there shouldn't be an issue but there is.
Help :(
This is the ChannelController.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ChannelController extends Controller
{
    public function edit(Channel $channel){

        return view('channel.edit', compact('channel'));

    }
}


And this is the Web.php with route
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\ChannelController;


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');



Route::middleware('auth')->group( function() {

    Route::get('/channel/{channel}/edit', [ChannelController::class, 'edit'])->name('channel.edit');
});



did you do a composer dump-autoload before?

I did try that, nothing changed the same error stayed.

Your controller needs to know where the Channel model is defined. Add a use statement for the model:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Channel;      //  <<< Add this line
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ChannelController extends Controller
{
    public function edit(Channel $channel){

        return view('channel.edit', compact('channel'));

    }
}

Although laravel can automatically detect many classes, perform dependency injection, and as in this case, do route model binding, you still have to include the class declaration.
